# implement list of user's facebook friends that are also using my application

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to implement an Android activity witch shows a list of images of the user's friends that use the same app also (like in Tinder app). I've searched the web for days and everything I found is too old or doesn't seem to work properly (mainly because they are all based on earlier versions of facebook SDK). 
Can somebody please attached an explanation, or even better, an open source of example like that.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the docs. I wonder how you didn't find that...

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends

Comment: it not the same thing...in this link it show you all the friends list . i need only thus who use this app

Comment: That's not really correct. '/me/friends' will always only return those friends which are using the app since Graph Api V2.0. It's all in the docs.